# How can I disable the ring shadow with TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css, input-field

This is how my problem looks like (see the ring)  :

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLCE0.png)

Using the Chrome's inspector found that it is related to `--tw-ring-shadow`.
So I tried adding classes like `ring-0` and `ring-offset-0` (as you can see below) but it didn't work!!

```
    import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
    
    
    function ContactForm(): JSX.Element {
      return (
        <div className="form-container pt-12 flex flex-col items-center">
          <div className="input-row">
            <TextField
              className="ring-offset-0 ring-0"
              label="First Name"
              variant="outlined"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default ContactForm;
```

Do you have any idea for how can I get rid of this annoying border that overlaps the input field??

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you tried to apply `shadow-none`?

Comment: Hi Levi, I've just tried now. Unfortunately, it didn't work. is there a way to edit via the tailwind.config.js?

Comment: if I disable --tw-ring-shadow via the inspector it works.. so annoying
see here: https://i.imgur.com/tVObEDa.png

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try overriding the Tailwind CSS variable for input fields by adding the following in your application's CSS:

```css
input {
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #000 !important;
}
```

Alternatively...we can't see the code generated by `<Textfield>` to ensure that your Tailwind utility classes are being applied correctly to the input element, but if they are not, you could try targeting the `<input>` field directly using `@apply` in your CSS file:

```css
input {
  @apply ring-offset-0 ring-0
}
```

Comment: It worked! just tried the first solution you suggested. Thank you!