# How to Disable MUI DatePicker Focus Highlight But Keep TextField Focus Highlight?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a date picker in react.js with MUI DatePicker. The code is almost exactly what their [documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#BasicDatePicker.js) has used.

However, when the component renders, I get two layers of blue color focus outline. One from `DatePicker` and one from `TextField`. This causes the `DatePicker` label to look like it's crossed out. I've struggled to get this working for days now.

I have tried playing with:

- InputProps
- Style tag
- className

But no luck. I'm relatively new to front-end any help is much appreciated.

**This is what I get:**

[image: This is what I get]

**This is what I want to achieve:** (I have set TextField to `focused` just for the sake of displaying what I need to achieve here):

[image]

Here's my implementation of the `DatePicker`:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} adapterLocale={localeMap.en}>
    <Box m={2}>
        <DatePicker
            showToolbar={false}
            views={["year", "month", "day"]}
            openTo="day"
            label="Day"
            maxDate={new Date()}
            value={v}
            onChange={setV}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                {...params}
                helperText={null}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                />
                )}
        />
    </Box>
</LocalizationProvider>
<button type="submit" onClick={fetchReports}
    className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font 
    medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 
    focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800 border-black">
    Get Report
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work by overriding --tw-ring-shadow from tailwind base. The answer @ed-lucas has given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353450/how-can-i-disable-the-ring-shadow-with-tailwindcss) worked for me too.

In the `index.css` added the following to override the default behavior.

```
input {
    --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks you saved my day, just to be accurate you can specify a className for the datepicker then specify this .className input {} (your answer), to not affect on other inputs

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late, but today I had the same problem and spent almost all of my day. So, I hope this will save some time to anyone else.

You can add className="MyDatePicker" for example:

```
<DatePicker
    showToolbar={false}
    views={["year", "month", "day"]}
    openTo="day"
    label="Day"
    maxDate={new Date()}
    value={v}
    onChange={setV}
    className="MyDatePicker"
/>
```

Then on the css file just add these classes:

```css
.MyDatePicker fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border: 2px solid #1976d2;
}
.MyDatePicker .Mui-focused fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: #1976d2;
}
```